# Tuning Order XGBoost

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, optimization, boosting

A random forest in XGBoost has a lot of hyperparameters to tune. I have seen examples where people search over a handful of parameters at a time and others where they search over all of them simultaneously. What are some approaches for tuning the XGBoost hyper-parameters? And what is the rational for these approaches?

Comment: I think you question should be modified a little. "best" - there is not answer for that. ask something like "what are some good methods" to do tuning?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good article on the topic:

[Complete Guide to Parameter Tuning in XGBoost (with codes in Python)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/)

Also, some people have had good success using [hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) for tuning hyperparameters.  Amine Benhalloum provides some Python code for tuning XGBoost: https://github.com/bamine/Kaggle-stuff/tree/master/otto

Answer (score 2):

```
param_grid = {
    'silent': [1],
    'max_depth': [4,5,6,7],
    'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0,3],
    'subsample': [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
    'colsample_bylevel': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
    'min_child_weight': [0.5, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0],
    'gamma': [0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0],
    'reg_lambda': [0.1, 1.0, 5.0, 10.0, 50.0, 100.0],
    'n_estimators': [100]}
    fit_params = {'eval_metric': 'logloss',
          'early_stopping_rounds': 10,
          'eval_set': [(X_train_tfidf, y_train_tfidf)],
          'verbose' : False
          }

    clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
    randomized_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_grid, n_iter=30,
                        n_jobs=-1, verbose=0, cv=5,
                        fit_params=fit_params,
                        scoring='neg_log_loss', refit=False, random_state=42)
    randomized_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```